# How to repent from apostasy?

Tags: tawba, apostasy

What is the process of repentance? I know about the feeling of regret and the resolve to never repeat the sin again that form the basis of repentance but is there a prayer that has to be said by a muslim who has blashphemed or is it just enough to say astaghfirullah?

Answer (score -1):

Quran says that only good deeds can compensate the evil deeds so try to compensate like that.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Although your statement is correct we expect answers here to be **well elaborated**, focused on answering the initial question and the claims **supported by evidences**. So please consider elaborating your answer!